# Angular2: Exception "No provider for t!" when creating a form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

```
<div id="my-form" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" ngControl="name" #n="ngForm" required>
    <div [hidden]="n.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
      Value is required
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the following (less than helpful) error with alpha.52:

> EXCEPTION: No provider for t! (t-> t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular registers controls under their ngControl names with the NgForm.  Normally, you don't have to add the NgForm directive explicitly because it automatically gets added – if you use a `<form>` element.  But you don't have a `<form>` element (which BTW is valid/fine as far as Twitter Bootstrap is concerned... but not Angular so much).  So, either change the outer `<div>` to `<form>`:

```
<form id="my-form" class="form-inline">
```

Or add the NgForm directive:

```
<div ngForm id="my-form" class="form-inline">
```