# No provider for t! on checkbox input

Tags: angular

In my app I have a checkbox which has show and dont show option, based on the selection loading the component. By default checkbox will be checked(component wont display) and based on the service value component will be display along with updating the check box selection.  It's working as expected in local (dev mode) but issue in prod build on server only.

**Html Code For check Box:**

```
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="changedivStatus()" class="md-primary" [(ngModel)]="showReport" />    <span>DO NOT SHOW</span>
```

**Service code on the updating the variable:**

```
        this.appReportsService.getUserPreference().subscribe(preference => {
                    if (preference[0].appPreferenceValue == 1) {
                        this.loadReport = true;
                        console.log(this.loadReport);
                    } else {
                        this.showReport = true;
                    }
                },
                (err) => { },
                () => { }
                );
```

**Module Code:**

```
import { NgModule }               from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }          from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule }         from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModule }          from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,FormsModule ,RouterModule,SharedModule ]})

export class DashboardModule {

}
```

Getting ERROR Error: No provider for t! error only after setting the  this.loadReport value true from the subscribe.

Comment: can you add your module

Comment: where you use loadReport variable? could you show thic part of code?

Comment: public loadReport : boolean = false;<app-app-reports [items]="apps" *ngIf="loadReport"></app-app-reports>

Answer (score 1):

I belive that's because you're not declaring the `provider` for your service in the module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {AppReportsService} from './path/to/your/service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: [
        AppReportsService
    ]})

    export class DashboardModule {}
```

Comment: In dashboard.component.ts already loaded the services . dashboard folder inside dashboard.component.ts, dashboard.component.html outside of the folder dashboard.module.ts

Comment: @Govindaraj even though you import it in the component you still need to declare it as a provider in the module

Comment: SharedModule has the all the services with provider the same loaded in the dashboard module i have updated the dashboard module file though same error.

Comment: in that case I'm not sure what the problem can be. are you using your `<input>` inside a `<form>` as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768631/angular2-exception-no-provider-for-t-when-creating-a-form#33768632 ? I didn't test to see if it realy breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You must have declared any private variable in your component file and used it in your html file of the respective component... Please check if there's any

Comment: can u please include the component file's code in your question